Error message “User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue” when trying to retract a delete vote
There is an existing question about the same error but when trying to unfollow: Error message “User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue” when unfollowing posts. By all means close this question as duplicate if the issue has a shared cause.
Details if important:

I had the issue on Stack Overflow.
My delete vote has not been retracted.


Same as this one which is resolved as of 2 minutes ago. Sorry, folks!

Per the above comment, this was confirmed to have the same cause as Error message “User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue” when undoing certain actions by staff.
